# Hide WooCommerce Store Notice if from United States

Tags: html, woocommerce

At: www.TattiniBoots.com/Shop you see that there is a red store notice at the top.

Is there a way to hide this if the current viewer has a United States IP address?

Comment: Could you provide more details?

What plugin/setting are you using to display the notice? What theme are you using?...

Comment: This is simply the default store notice feature located within all Wordpress Woocommerce sites. Maybe the best option is to use a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the follows code snippet to do so -

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_demo_store', 'modify_woocommerce_demo_store', 99 );

function modify_woocommerce_demo_store( $notice_html ) {
    // Get geolocated user geo data.
    $user_geodata = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();
    if( $user_geodata && !isset( $user_geodata['country'] ) ) return $notice_html;
    if( $user_geodata['country'] == 'US' ) return '';
    return $notice_html;
}
```

Codes goes to your active theme's functions.php

Comment: I am trying to hide the notice IF the user is from the United States. This code is not currently working for me

Comment: The above codes is tested and working properly. It may be related something with theme. Can you check this with default theme.

Comment: It literally breaks the site: "The site is experiencing technical difficulties"

Comment: This is a tested codes. Can you please double check you codes with the above that you are missing something or not.

Comment: This is working now. For those of you attempting to do the same thing, ensure that you have the MaxMind License Key set up in WooCommerce>Settings>Integrations

Answer (score 0):

In the Woocommerce admin, go to `Settings > General`. There will be an option under "General options" for "Default customer location". Set this value to "Geolocate".

In your theme or plugin, you can use the function `wc_get_customer_default_location()`, which returns an array of containing country and state. Simply check the value of country in the array to see if it matches 'US' and modify your code as needed.

Comment: This is simply the default store notice feature located within all Wordpress Woocommerce sites. Maybe the best option is to use a plugin